# Connection to Big Query from Power BI - Partitioned Table

Tags: powerbi

I'm currently trying to import data from Big Query to Power BI, but have been receiving the below error when I load the data to Power BI.

DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][BigQuery] (70) Invalid query: Cannot query over table 'xxxxx' without a filter over column(s) 'date' that can be used for partition elimination

I've tried changing the type for the column "date", but it didn't resolve the error.

Comment: Please add your query to your question. I think you should adjust the conditions of the date part in your query.

Comment: another suggestion is to change the DATETIME operation with TIMESTAMP... do you have any DATETIME operation in your query ? did you try this query in excel ? the same result ? and i believe this is not a Power BI issue actually...